# Disprove $(2^n)^{\frac{1}{3}} \in \theta(2^n)$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I know we can prove this simply by saying we can't find such $c_1,c_2$ but the question asks me to prove this by proving its negation is true. (the hint of the problem says this will be hard)

We negate the definition, $\exists c_{1}, c_{2}, \forall n \geq n_{0}, c_{1} 2^{n} \leq\left(2^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq c_{2} 2^{n}$, and get $\forall c_{1}, n_{0} \exists n \geq n_{0},\left(2^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq c_{1} 2^{n}$.

I'm thinking of breaking $c_1$into either positive or negative case. What I felt confused about is $\forall n_0,\exists n\geq n_0$, How can we approach this? Is there any difference between this and $\exists n_0 \forall n\geq n_0$?

Comment: Simply saying that we can’t find suitable $c_1$ and $c_2$ proves nothing at all. The only way to disprove the assertion is to prove that it is false, i.e., that its negation is true. In other words, you have to prove that $(2^n)^{\frac13}\notin\Theta\left(2^n\right)$, exactly what you were told to do.

Comment: why we can't say we can't find such $c_1,c_2,n_0$ to prove the problem? How about "Suppose we can find, then contradiction?"

Comment: Because just saying it proves nothing. You have to **prove** that you can’t find them. Just saying it would be like saying that you can’t find an $x$ such that $2+x=5$: it proves nothing. And in fact in this case we **can** find such an $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How about "Suppose there exists such $c_1,c_2,n_0$, then contradiction?"

Comment: That would work, assuming that you could in fact derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that for all constants $c_1$, and for all $n_0\in \mathbb N$, there will exist $n\ge n_0$ such that $$c_12^n> 2^{n/3}.$$ This will prove the lowed bound cannot be satisfied. This is equivalent to $n> \frac32\log_2(1/c_1)$, so simply choose $n$ to be $\max(n_0,\lceil \frac32\log_2(1/c_1)\rceil)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $2^n \leq C (2^n)^{\frac13}$ then $2^{\frac{2n}{3}} \leq C$. This can't hold as $n\to\infty$.
In other words, $2^n$ grows faster than $2^{\frac n3}$.
It's better to try to understand problems intuitively than to write a bunch of formal symbols and get yourself mixed up.

Abstractly, $\exists y\ \forall x$ says the same $y$ works for every $x$.
Whereas $\forall y\ \exists x$ says you're allowed to pick a different $y$ for each $x$.

Comment: hmmm of course it's easy in this way. But I need to prove it

Comment: First prove by induction that $2^m > m$. Therefore, given C, there exists $m$ such that $2^m > C$. Then take $n = 2m$. You have $2^{\frac23 n} > 2^m > C$.

Comment: but induction only holds for natural number right? What if I want to prove for all constants?

Comment: The value of $n$ depends on your constant $C$. There is no single $n$ that works for all $C$.